Can't find TMP_Text or TextMeshPro using GetComponent


I'm trying to find the Text component, which is on the Title object. My script is on the Cat object:
private TMP_Text titleText; // Also tried private TextMeshPro titleText;

private void Awake()
{
    titleText = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    Debug.Log(titleText); //always NULL
    titleText.text = "Test";  // NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
}

I've tried both TextMeshPro and TMP_Text. I've also tried looping through children, but my understanding is that GetComponent() is supposed to do that recursively.

It's probably TextMeshProUGUI. You can see the script/class name of a component by switching to debug mode on the component menu.

@ErikOverflow thanks for the tip on debug mode. For Script it says "TextMeshPro" though. I specifically didn't want the Canvas version for this because it's text on a character prefab - think a name above the character's head.

The same still applies to find out what the component is called, also GetComponent only checks current object GetComponentInChildren gets it from child objects

@ErikOverflow if using TMP_Text which is the parent of both TextMeshPro and TextMeshProUGUI it doesn't matter which one you use .. and no, what OP shows indeed is the 3D world space TextMeshPro  (otherwise the Inspector would say TextMeshPro - Text (UI) and have a CanvasRenderer instead of the MeshRenderer)

Why not rather expose this to the Inspector instead of using GetComponent at all? [SerializeField] private TMP_Text titleText;

@derHugo I'd love to, but I can't drag the TextMeshPro component, which is on the Title object, to the Cat script on the parent object.

Hm works for me .. I wonder what details we don't know that would prevent that ...

@derHugo Turns out the issue was that I had a stray component on a different game object that also had this script on it but didn't have a TextMeshPro assigned to it - that was the one complaining about the null error, and explains why the text got updated properly on the other one.

The GetComponent function only finds components of the object it is called on. Since your script is attached to the Cat object, the function looks for a TextMeshPro component which is also attached to the Cat object. If you want to find the text, you will have to call the get GetComponent function for the Title object which can be found using the Transform.Find() function which in your case can be done as shown below:
titleText = transform.Find("UI/Title").gameObject.GetComponent<TMP_Text>();


Ok, so that throws a UnityException: Transform child out of bounds error in the Console, but setting the text after that somehow still works?

I edited my response, so it should work better now. The way I suggested previously relied on a specific ordering of the child objects in the hierarchy which can cause problems.

Appreciate it. Now I see NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Yet again, it does set the text.

I tried this: transform.Find("UI/Title").gameObject.GetComponents(typeof(Component)); and the list shows a RectTransform, a MeshRenderer, a TMPro.TextMeshPro, and a MeshFilter. I tried replacing TMP_Text with TextMeshPro but I get the same error.
